# How do I get Outlook to select the newest email in a folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have my emails sorted from newest to oldest (newest at the top). But whenever I go to a folder, Outlook always selects/highlights my oldest email at the bottom. I want it to select the newest email instead.

Comment: Different folders can have different sort rules. Are you sure that all the folders are sorted the same way?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I even applied the current view settings to all folders and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does it happen if you [Open Outlook in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-outlook-in-safe-mode-f394c2ee-b2af-e97a-64ee-35cd24414811)?

Comment: Have you tried repairing office?